# Uso de laravel en firefox

Tags: laravel, firefox, programación-funcional, navegador-web

Al usar en navegador firefox, al momento de iniciar seccion, y estar en el home, si volvemos atras, aparecera el login, aunque tenga validado el auth, al igaul si uso

```
> @if(Auth::check())
>     <div>
>        Esta logeado
>     </div> 
 @endif
```

para la comprobacion del usuario, sin embargo solo el codigo fuente es modificado, pero en la vista no cambia nada.

Comment: Trata de borrar caché o utilizando el modo incógnito

Comment: Y con los otros navegadores no te pasa eso ?